# Parse data from several equally structured blocks of a text file in python

Tags: python, regex, list, dataframe, parsing

I've got a text file that has several of these blocks of text in it:

```
Module Resistor_SMD:R_0402_1005Metric (layer B.Cu) (tedit 5B301BBD) (tstamp 5CC0A687)
    (at 120.316179 97.92138 90)
    (descr "Resistor SMD 0402 (1005 Metric), square (rectangular) end terminal, IPC_7351 nominal, (Body size source: http://www.tortai-tech.com/upload/download/2011102023233369053.pdf), generated with kicad-footprint-generator")
    (tags resistor)
    (path /610532D4)
    (attr smd)
    (fp_text reference R59 (at 0 1.17 90) (layer B.SilkS)
```

I want to pull out the following:
`120.316179, 97.92138 90 and R59`

and store it somewhere...

Then, I want to take that collection of line items, and throw some away depending on the value(s) of the first two numbers....They're XY coordinates.

Then, write it to a list.

How can I do that with regular expressions?
I'm loading the file and trying to follow along [here](https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/), but I'm getting lost in the addition of the pandas library.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you don't need `re` for this task. You can iterate through the lines of your file and, depending on signal strings like `'(at '` and `'fp_text reference'`, you can fill a list of lists of all your resistor data, e.g.:

```
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    data = []
    row = []
    for line in f:
        if row:
            if '(fp_text ref' in line.strip():
                row.append(line.strip().split()[2])
                data.append(row)
                row = []
        else:
            if '(at ' in line.strip():
                row = line.strip()[:-1].split()[1:4]

print(data)

# [['120.316179', '97.92138', '90', 'R59']]
```

And if you want a pandas dataframe from this data:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'R'])
print(df)

#             x         y   z    R                            
# 0  120.316179  97.92138  90  R59
```

Comment: Woooooorrrrrdddd... That's what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/aqIzjW/1) might help you to capture your three desired strings:

```
([\d]+\.[\d]{5,}|R[0-9]+)
```

- There are two simple pattern connected using an <kbd>|</kbd> (OR):

  - the one on the left (`[\d]+\.[\d]{5,}`) checks for your desired float numbers with a 5+ boundary for the float part, and
  - the one on the right (`R[0-9]+`) has a left-side <kbd>R</kbd> boundary.
- You can simply change these boundaries, however you wish, and call the captured output using <kbd>$1</kbd> and do the coding.
- You can escape language specific metachars such as <kbd>.</kbd> using a <kbd>\</kbd>, if necessary.

[image]

Comment: How does that get saved in a df?  because the R9 occurs on a separate line from the XY coordinates

Comment: Thanks... The re library is still confusing to me, so this helps!